What is the purpose of `function _transfer()` in this contract?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

interface tokenRecipient {
  function receiveApproval(
    address _from,
    uint256 _value,
    address _token,
    bytes calldata _extraData
  ) external;
}

contract TokenERC20 {
  // Public variables of the token
  string public name;
  string public symbol;
  uint8 public decimals = 18;
  // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
  uint256 public totalSupply;

  // This creates an array with all balances
  mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
  mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

  // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

  // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
  event Approval(
    address indexed _owner,
    address indexed _spender,
    uint256 _value
  );

  // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
  event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

  /**
   * Constructor function
   *
   * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
   */
  constructor(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string memory tokenName,
    string memory tokenSymbol
  ) {
    totalSupply = initialSupply * 10**uint256(decimals); // Update total supply with the decimal amount
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply; // Give the creator all initial tokens
    name = tokenName; // Set the name for display purposes
    symbol = tokenSymbol; // Set the symbol for display purposes
  }

  /**
   * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
   */
  function _transfer(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _value
  ) internal {
    // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require(_to != address(0x0));
    // Check if the sender has enough
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    // Check for overflows
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
    // Save this for an assertion in the future
    uint256 previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
    // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    // Add the same to the recipient
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
    assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
  }

  /**
   * Transfer tokens
   *
   * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
   *
   * @param _to The address of the recipient
   * @param _value the amount to send
   */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Transfer tokens from other address
   *
   * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` on behalf of `_from`
   *
   * @param _from The address of the sender
   * @param _to The address of the recipient
   * @param _value the amount to send
   */
  function transferFrom(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _value
  ) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]); // Check allowance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Set allowance for other address
   *
   * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf
   *
   * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
   * @param _value the max amount they can spend
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
    public
    returns (bool success)
  {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Set allowance for other address and notify
   *
   * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
   *
   * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
   * @param _value the max amount they can spend
   * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
   */
  function approveAndCall(
    address _spender,
    uint256 _value,
    bytes memory _extraData
  ) public returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
      spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, address(this), _extraData);
      return true;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Destroy tokens
   *
   * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
   *
   * @param _value the amount of money to burn
   */
  function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value); // Check if the sender has enough
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value; // Subtract from the sender
    totalSupply -= _value; // Updates totalSupply
    emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Destroy tokens from other account
   *
   * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
   *
   * @param _from the address of the sender
   * @param _value the amount of money to burn
   */
  function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value)
    public
    returns (bool success)
  {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value); // Check if the targeted balance is enough
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]); // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value; // Subtract from the targeted balance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value; // Subtract from the sender's allowance
    totalSupply -= _value; // Update totalSupply
    emit Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
  }
}


It is only internal as a design pattern, the internal implementation can then be called via the externally exposed transfer or from within other functions such as transerFrom without rewriting the same lines.
The purpose is to update balances held in storage.
It isn't for any special internal transfer.

Are you saying we have the _transfer() so that we can use in other functions within the contract?

Yes so that you can use it within other functions, without having to rewrite it. Reducing the surface area for potential issues. Less code to audit, less chance of making a mistake in one of the occurrences.

You can ask these kind of questions related to what a function is supposed to do or so, from a generative AI like ChatGPT, Gemini, etc.
I’ve got the following response from ChatGPT, and it seems pretty detailed and correct.
The _transfer() function in this contract is an internal function that handles the logic for transferring tokens from one address to another. Here’s a breakdown of its purpose and how it works:

Internal Function: _transfer() is marked as internal, meaning it can only be called within the contract itself or by derived contracts. It cannot be called externally by users or other contracts.

Prevents Transfers to Zero Address: The function checks if the recipient address (_to) is not the zero address (0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ). If it is, the function reverts. This ensures that tokens cannot be sent to an invalid address where they would effectively be burned without using the burn() function.

Balance Check: The function checks whether the sender (_from) has enough balance to complete the transfer. If not, the function reverts.

Overflow Check: It checks for overflows in the recipient’s balance by ensuring that adding the transfer amount to the recipient’s balance doesn’t exceed the maximum allowed value.

Balance Update: The sender’s balance is reduced by the amount of tokens being transferred (_value), and the recipient’s balance is increased by the same amount.

Event Emission: After updating the balances, the function emits a Transfer event, which is a standard event in ERC20 contracts that logs the details of the transfer. This event can be picked up by off-chain applications to track token transfers.

Assertion for Consistency: Finally, the function uses an assert statement to ensure that the total balance of the sender and recipient before and after the transfer remains consistent. This serves as an additional safety check to catch any unexpected behavior.


In summary, the _transfer() function encapsulates the core logic for transferring tokens within the contract, ensuring that all necessary checks and balance updates are performed in a secure and consistent manner.

I have used chatGPT before coming here. From the repo I copied this the function is for internal transfer within the contract. I don't understand what that means.
Can tokens be transfer within the same smart contract ?

Here is the full code
https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-erc20-fcc/blob/main/contracts/ManualToken.sol

Actually, it’s a contract that can be used as a MockERC20, it’s not transferring tokens, rather it’s storing the balance of the token (i.e., the contract itself) in its storage.

So, with the transfer, it’s just updating the internal balances mapping, corresponding to the from and to addresses.

Does immutable work for string?
Like string public immutable name

No, because string is considered as a dynamic data type like array.

Thanks mate, I appreciate
